# Setup git hooks directory automatically on the first load of mvn project in Intellij or any other IDE

Tags: git, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

In the company, we are working with multiple projects which are using maven.

Is it possible to execute the script that will automatically set up the local git hooks directory when the project will be open in IDE?
In the Gradle, there is a possibility to do it with Gradle.projectsEvaluated method. Does exist some equivalent of this method in maven?

I need a solution that will be executed when someone first loads the project, so the solution with running mvn clean/install, etc is not the solution I need.

Changing git hooks directory is needed to execute script on pre-commit which runs code formatter.

Comment: Why do you need a hook locally? What kind of task do you need to execute? A hook for code formatting? That should be configured correctly in your IDE to format your code during the save options..can easily be configured in IntelliJ...

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a script to automatically do this when opening in an IDE or other editor, because there are a variety of editors and they all work differently.  Moreover, automatically executing code when opening a file in an editor would be a security vulnerability.  What if the code were some untrusted project found online?

[As outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt#restrict-with-hooks), you don't want to mandate the use of hooks because they can be trivially bypassed and advanced users can and do use many workflows which can make working with them inconvenient.  You may choose to provide them and a script to install them and let users decide whether or not to install them.

Your repository should also contain the configuration file for whatever code formatting tool you use.  At that point, users can easily configure their editor to run it on save or with a keyboard shortcut.

If you want to enforce coding standards, that should be done in your CI system.  Ideally you have a single coding standards job that runs quickly so if a user makes a mistake they can notice quickly and fix it.